# how to set limits on ldap search results in Erlang

Tags: ldap, erlang, elixir, limit

How can we specify a **limit** when making a search request with `:eldap.search/2` to avoid:

`{:error, :sizeLimitExceeded}`

There is no mention of ***setting limits*** on search, or ***pagination*** in the [eldap docs](https://erlang.org/doc/man/eldap.html#search-2)

Comment: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/899811898afce4c5b296c43d12af06cc920e05c0/lib/eldap/src/eldap.erl#L752 maybe you can check that one

Answer (score 1):

From @Tano comment, it's actually set in the `:eldap` source as `sizeLimit = 0` (no size limit?), so I guess we can override this.

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/899811898afce4c5b296c43d12af06cc920e05c0/lib/eldap/src/eldap.erl#L748-L757

```
do_search_0(Data, A, Controls) ->
    Req = #'SearchRequest'{baseObject = A#eldap_search.base,
               scope = v_scope(A#eldap_search.scope),
               derefAliases = v_deref(A#eldap_search.deref),
               sizeLimit = 0, % no size limit
               timeLimit = v_timeout(A#eldap_search.timeout),
               typesOnly = v_bool(A#eldap_search.types_only),
               filter = v_filter(A#eldap_search.filter),
               attributes = v_attributes(A#eldap_search.attributes)
              },
```